# Can not switch to a branch in Source tree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have never used git or gitlab or sourcetree before, now I cloned a project and I tried to switch to a branch, but I get an error, I understood by tis error message that I made some local changes but I did not.

Here is the branch I am trying to switch to : [image]

but I get this error in SourceTree : [image]

I tried to write some command lines, such as git stach but, I get a response telling me no local changes has been made [image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: _"The following ***untracked*** working tree files would be overwritten by checkout"_.  Given it is untracked, stash won't include it.  Just remove the file manually, or git add then git stash, and it should work.  Or, just do a `git checkout --force` and it should force overwritting such kind of files too

Comment: @AdrianShum what can cause the problem then ?

Comment: oops, I thought the error message already explain the problem so I haven't further explain.  To be clear:  1. you have a untracked file in your working tree  2. The commit you are checking out contains a file with the same name.  Git will try not to overwrite your local work silently, hence the error you see

Comment: I tried git add * and then git stash but it did not work

Comment: It is hard to guess.  Probably you are in another directory (not parent of the untracked file), and, as `*` is expanded by the shell, what you are adding to git has nothing to do with the untracked file.  You may simply do `git status` to check what is untracked, and do a `git add` to add it.  Or, in your `.gitignore`, you have that file ignored (so the file exists, but git ignore it, so it is untracked).  But someone else committed that file in the branch you are checking out, which makes git avoid to overwrite your file